# Distinct on two columns on a SELECT

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, `DATA` and `FILES`

`DATA` table :

```
+---------+------------+-----------+--------+--------
| ID      |   FILES_ID |  TYPE     |  NAME  |  VALUE
+---------+------------+-----------+--------+--------
| 1       |      1     |  TYPE_A   |  A1    |  10
| 2       |      1     |  TYPE_A   |  A1    |  15
| 3       |      2     |  TYPE_B   |  B1    |  10
| 4       |      3     |  TYPE_C   |  CA    |  1
| 5       |      4     |  TYPE_B   |  BL    |  54
| 6       |      5     |  TYPE_C   |  CA    |  28
| 7       |      6     |  TYPE_B   |  B1    |  44
```

`FILES` table :

```
+---------+---------------
| ID      |  CREATED_DATE
+---------+--------------
| 1       | 2023-03-10 19:52:41     
| 2       | 2023-03-11 19:52:41    
| 3       | 2023-03-12 19:52:41     
| 4       | 2023-03-13 19:52:41   
| 5       | 2023-03-14 19:52:41     
| 6       | 2023-03-15 19:52:41
```

I want the distinct combination data.type - data.name with the newest date where this data combination where imported ( so based on the created_date on FILES table ) and ordered by created_date DESC

In my example this is what I want :

```
    +---------+------------+---------------
    | TYPE    |   NAME     |  CREATED_DATE|
    +---------+------------+---------------
    | TYPE_B  |      B1    |  2023-03-15 19:52:41
    | TYPE_C  |      CA    |  2023-03-14 19:52:41 
    | TYPE_B  |      BL    |  2023-03-13 19:52:41   
    | TYPE_A  |      A1    |  2023-03-11 19:52:41
```

I've tried multiple SQL queries without success I don't know how to do that ...
I hope you guys that someone will help me to permit to do that and to understand how you did that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check your expected output once; As per explanation; The first two rows should be different;
`TYPE_B BL 2023-03-13 19:52:41`
and
`TYPE_C CA 2023-03-12 19:52:41`

Please let me know, if I am wrong in uderstanding requirement

Comment: thanks @Tushar , I did a mistake on the data table, I've updated the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Postgres, we can use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (d.TYPE, d.NAME) d.TYPE, d.NAME, f.CREATED_DATE
FROM DATA d
INNER JOIN FILES f
    ON f.ID = d.FILES_ID
ORDER BY d.TYPE, d.NAME, f.CREATED_DATE DESC;
```

If you want to order the result set by name and date, then use:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (d.TYPE, d.NAME) d.TYPE, d.NAME, f.CREATED_DATE
    FROM DATA d
    INNER JOIN FILES f ON f.ID = d.FILES_ID
    ORDER BY d.TYPE, d.NAME, f.CREATED_DATE DESC
)

SELECT TYPE, NAME, CREATED_DATE
FROM cte
ORDER BY NAME, CREATED_DATE;
```

Comment: thank you it works, the small "issue" is that it's ordering by the distinct columns, is it possible to order by name and after by created_date ?

Comment: @Fizik26 Yes...place my answer into a CTE and then subquery to order as you want.